# how can i declare a C++ array of 10 pointers to objects of a class?

Tags: c++, arrays

Assume a circle class has been implemented. how can I declare an array of 10 pointers to objects of the circle class?

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your code, and explain what your question is. Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question almost every time. It then gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I **declare** an array of 10 pointers to objects of the circle class?

Like this:

```
circle* myArray[10];
```

It is then your responsibility to assign those pointers to point at valid `circle` objects. But how you do that exactly is outside the scope of your question, as you did not explain how you intend to use the `circle` class or this array.